# Turning a long if statement with many &&'s into a for loop with javascript

Tags: javascript

For Project Euler problem 5, I've created this brute force solution.

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

```
function smallest(){
    for (let i = 1; ;i++){
        if(i%1==0 && i%2==0 && i%3==0 && i%4==0 && i%5==0 && i%6==0 && i%7==0 && i%8==0 && i%9==0 && i%10==0 
          && i%11==0 && i%12==0 && i%13==0 && i%14==0 && i%15==0 && i%16==0 && i%17==0 && i%18==0 && i%19==0 && i%20==0){
          console.log(i);
          return i;
        }
    }     
}
smallest();
```

Is there a way I can create a for loop to do this in one step instead?
Whenever I try some combination of

```
for (j = 1; j <= 20; j++){
    if (i%j == 0){
        console.log(i);
        return(i);
```

it just ends up crashing...
I've only been learning for 3 months so beginner friendly help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Trying the different denominators and `return`ing `i` on the first match is like an OR condition.

Comment: Your proposed code doesn't appear to have closing curly braces for the `if` statement or for the `for` loop.  Also, `return` is not a function, but you're calling it like one. Should be `return i` without parentheses.

Comment: @Marc: True, however `return i` and `return (i)` are identical. The grouping operator returns the value of its operand.

Comment: I think the Project Euler way of doing this would be to think about the prime factorization of the numbers from 2 to 20. By knowing the necessary "pool" of primes needed for those values, you can then multiply them together and get the result directly.

Comment: `const oneToTwenty = Array.from({ length: 20 }, (_, u) => u + 1); if (oneToTwenty.every(n => i % n === 0))`

Comment: Given the problem has a static in- and output, the fastest way would obviously be to just return the result, but i don't think it's the point of the question, solutions are all over the internet.

Comment: For your other question.. replace all if statment with elseif in file signup.inc.php except thefirst one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second loop, there's no reference to `i`, so the if statement of `i % j` is invalid.

You need a nested `for` loop here:

```
for (i = 1; ; i++) {
    let divisible = true;
    for (j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
        if (i % j != 0) {
            divisible = false;
        }
     }
     if (divisible) {
        return (i);
     }
}
```

This seareches for the smallest `i`, checking if that value is divisible by `j` as it increases from 1 to 20. The trick here is to assume that it will, and set a flag if the `i` value is not divisible by one of the `j` values. We can check that flag after the second loop is completed; if it's still true, then we can return that `i` value! The flag is reset at the next iteration of the first for loop, giving us a clean slate each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```js
function smallest(){
    let num = 1;
    let isDivisible = false;
    while(! isDivisible){
        // Start off with the assumption that it is divisible
        isDivisible = true;
    
        for(let x = 1; x <= 20 && isDivisible; x++){
            if( num % x !== 0 ){
                isDivisible = false;
                num++;
            }
        }
    
    }

    return num;
}

console.log(smallest());
```

Comment: Fixed, before it was attempting to divide by 0

Answer (score 1):

You could get all factors of the given numers, collect reater exponents and build the product of all.

```js
function getValue(start, end) {
    function getFactors(value) {
        const result = {};
        for (let i = 2; value !== 1; i += 1 + (i > 2)) {
            while (value % i === 0) {
                value /= i;
                result[i] = (result[i] || 0) + 1;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    const temp = {};
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        Object
            .entries(getFactors(i))
            .forEach(([k, v]) => temp[k] = Math.max(v, temp[k] || 0));
    }
    return Object
        .entries(temp)
        .reduce((p, [b, e]) => p * b ** e, 1);
}

console.log(getValue(1, 10));
console.log(getValue(1, 20));
```